On which side shall I put the diamond sign in an UML diagram

I am trying to figure out where should the diamond be placed in this example, I understand its a has-a relationship and diamond should be placed to indicate the whole and part relationship.
I have created the UML so that the diamond is on the manufacturer side for both car and engine, like below

because it makes sense right? that the car and engine is being produced by the manufacturer, but the correct answer I was given in the class was to put the diamonds on car and engine respectively... it seems a bit odd to me since wouldn't the manufacturer be the "whole" in this relationship? Below is the spec:

I am trying to figure out where should I place the diamond sign

Does this answer your question? What does a diamond sign signify in UML class diagrams?

@VLAZ while the related answer is relevant, it does not really answer the question, since OP knows apparently well the principle of composition and has mainly a notational question. The side of the composition is not well explained in the answers to that other question and moreover most of them focus on shared aggregation.

@Christophe "The customer and order is a "has-a" composition relationship because if the customer ceases to exist so does his/her order." from this answer seems to explain very well to me what does placing a diamond next to one of the two entities mean. You've used the exact same language yourself with "if an engine is destroyed, so is the owned manufacturer"

Both models are wrong. If a manufacturer goes out of business, then your car continues to exist. If a car is squashed into a cube, then the manufacturer continues to exist.

@VLAZ The answer you refer is simply outdated since UML2.5 is in place. Refer there to page 110.

@JimL. Yes indeed. But there is a gradation in the wrongness. The first is completely wrong and inconsistent. The second does not corresponds to the reality that we expect, but could be defended in some software designs (e.g. if the model represents a sales catalogue of  vehicles and if a brand is removed from the catalogue, so are all the related cars and engines, typically the things you'd implement with a delete cascade in an RDBMS). In my answer I said that the second is "right in this regard" i.e. regarding the diamond's side  if a composition is needed, but at same time I advise against

@JimL. but thanks for pointing this out. I've clarified the wording of my answer to address the ambiguity :-)

@Christophe: the trouble is, this is about cars that we drive, not car types that we offer in a catalog.

The diagram of the top is wrong, given the specifications:

The black diamond ("composite aggregation" in UML-speak or "composition" as shortcut) on the side of the engine would mean that Engine owns Manufacturer, and in particular if an engine is destroyed,  so is the owned manufacturer.  Same principle for the Car.

Moreover, according to the UML specifications, an instance of Manufacturer can only belong to one composite at a time, either a n instance of Car or Engine, but not both at the same time.  Which is a nonsense in real life, where a manufacturer can produce many car and many engines at the same time.

The black diamond MUST be on the side of the owner.


If the top diagram is what was taught in the classroom,  the teacher has not understood UML very well, and you should consider a different guidance.
The diagram on the bottom is correct about the side of the diamond, but I'd recommend not to use composition at all. Here the comments to the second model:

Composition seems to be too strong.  Indeed,  I once bought a Chrysler car.  But when Chrysler disappeared to become Daimler-Chrysler,  my engine and my car were not destroyed. While one can argue the suitability of my example, and discuss the pros and cons of composition,  my advice is:  use composition, only if this kind of ownership is absolutely needed.  In all other cases, prefer a normal association.
Also the white diamond ("shared aggregation" in UML-speak or "aggregation" as an ambiguous shortcut), while still popular and used by millions of people, is in reality ambiguous and of no use.  Indeed the UML specifications do no longer define any semantic for it (and this since more than 20 years!).  Also here, prefer a simple association (unless you have to use it to please your teacher).
You may also want to use the official shortcut of * instead of 0..*.  The latter is correct, but the former is nicer to read and is officially defined in the UML specifications to be strictly equivalent.


Regarding the instance(!) the top diagram is NOT wrong since the composition is about instances and not about classes (I fell in thar trap once)

@qwerty_so yes,you are right.  This is what I said: an instance can not be a component of both at the same time, but can be either of the two. Concretely,  in the model of the top, if porsche_engine:Engine  composes the porsche:Manufacturer, the porsche_960:Car could not compose the same Manufacturer instance, which is plain wrong. The bottom model would allow the manufacturer to compose both the porsche_960 and the porsche_engine, but as explained,  although not wrong it does not correspond to expectations (see also my answer to Jim's comment why it's nevertheless not necessarily wrong)

Basically one should simply stay away from any aggregation since it add's more confusion than it brings value. There are only a few real applications where it makes sense. Mainly in a security environment.

@qwerty_so: as I see it, the top diagram is wrong. If you destroy a car, you don’t destroy the manufacturer. Moreover, composition must have max 1 cardinality, not *.

@JimL. I think we all agree. I understood qwerty_so's remark referring only to my remark on the double composition (because we had a discussion in another question and ended up agreeing after cross-checking each on our own side in the specs). So I said yes to him, that it's not wrong about that specific aspect, but I stand to my answer which states that it's plain wrong in general because of the semantics. Reading qwerty_so answer I don't have the impression that he means that the top is right in general. I let him nevertheless confirm

Thank you @Christophe !! this makes a lot of sense!

To give a simple answer: the filled diamond is placed on that classes side which controls the lifetime of the opposite one. Composite aggregation tells that "if I will die, you will die too". So this makes sense mostly only in a security environment where you want to enforce this exact situation. Almost nowhere else. (See also the comments below. There are more areas, but I think they are not ones visited by common UML users.)
Also read p. 110 of UML 2.5 which moreover get's somehow rid of the hollow diamond notation making it a semantic vapor.

Security environment? I think it’s usually more about retention of allocated space, although it could be applied to the destruction of real supervening objects, like me and my liver.

@JimL. A human body and the liver have a more complex relationship. On one side it's composite aggregation: if the body dies so does the liver, although, as UML allows, the liver can be transplanted just before and then have its lifecycle controlled by another body. But medically speaking it could be also the other way round: if the liver dies, so will probably the human body around it, unless it gets detached from the liver. From the UML point of view, if driven only by lifecycle control one could also defend a composite aggregation in opposite direction. But it's not allowed to have a ...

@JimL. ... a diamond on both ends of an association, is it ? So here again, I would recommend to prefer the simple association and explain the interdependency in a constraint ;-)  Joke apart, I'm not sure if I would drive the use of composite aggregation with implementation considerations like memory allocation. I'd rather go for  semantics, i.e. if the component has no meaning without its composite (in databases usually implemented with referential integrity and cascading delete/update)

@JimL. Well, we can go about philosophy, but honestly: who models a human body in UML? I think the esoteric ideas behind any kind of ccomposition is just meant for theoretical discussion and not about practical application. So: stay away from it...

UML can be used for ontologies (see OntoUML and Cameo Concept Modeler),  ontologies actually model real things, and one very successful use of ontologies is in biomedicine. Have you ever heard of the Gene Ontology associated with the Human Genome Project?

And philosophy absolutely helps us get models right.

@JimL. Heard, yes. Dealt with, no. I can see there is an area. But really, it's very sophisticated. And the usual suspect should simply not deal with aggregation. See, this already took us quite a bit off...

The answer depends on the purpose of the diagram.
In general, if A is composed of B (i.e. the diamond is on A's side) and an instance of A is deleted, then all instances of B composed by A are deleted as well.
If the purpose of the diagram is to model the real world, then no composition shall be used here at all. If a manufacturer ceases to exist, then its cars and engines continue to exist. If a car or an engine vanishes, then the manufacturer continues to exist.
If the purpose of the diagram is to model the information in a software application, then it depends on the behavior of this application:

If the application removes all cars and engines when their manufacturer is deleted, then the diamond shall be on the manufacturer's side.
If the application regards the manufacturer's data as a component of the car's data and as a component of the engine's data, then the diamond shall be on the car's and engine's sides. But in that case, the multiplicities of the relationships shall be 1-1 instead of 1-0..*. Every car and every engine has its own copy of the manufacturer's data. A single real-world manufacturer is then represented by many instances of the manufacturer class in the application. (This is an unlikely scenario in your case. But take classes Person and Address. In real world, several persons may live on the same address, but in many applications, each person record has its own copy of the address data).
In all other cases, composition is not applicable.

